# Access of local storage giving security error after cookies are disabled in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage

I am seeing weird behaviour in firefox. I have a small web app which uses local storage. I disable cookies and I run my app. It throws security error while accessing local storage. App does not run. On chrome app runs but a `uncaught_error : QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERROR` comes. Here's how I access local storage

```
_infSt = ((!!window.localStorage) && (!!window.atob));
if(_infSt){ 
    _infLJsV = window.localStorage.getItem( 'infJsV' );
    if(_infLJsV === _infJsV) {
        var strjL = window.localStorage.getItem( 'infJqN' );
        if(strjL != ''){ 
            inFjL = strjL;
        }
    }
}
```

in firefox 8.0 I get error while running `_infSt = ((!!window.localStorage) && (!!window.atob));` on this line. In firefox 10.00 I get error while trying to `atob(inFjL);`

How in this world, is disabling cookie and local storage linked? Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's linked because localStorage is just cookies on steroids: it's a way to save per-site data on the user's machine permanently, with read and write access for the one site.

So if a user disables cookies (for privacy reasons, say), they really want to disable localStorage as well.  That's what the browser does, therefore.

Comment: ok, but then why security error? Is it because, local storage was disabled and a domain tried to access it?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.  The options at that point are to throw or to silently do nothing, basically....